# How to distinguish user-defined / library functions from a compiled file?

Tags: user-defined-functions

**EDIT**:

What I want is to distinguish **statically linked** library functions and **user self-written** functions **within** a compiled file (e.g. PE file).

How to achieve that? (I am thinking of database comparison but I do not know any database.)

By the way, (I have already known long before I asked this question) for dynamically linked library functions, they are just an entry in the import table (of PE).

---

By library functions, I mean those defined in libraries, such as STL (I know this is a bad name).

By user-defined functions, I mean those written by individual programmers.

Is there any programmatic way to achieve this goal?

Right now I am thinking about comparing binaries with a database, but I do not know any database so far.

Please recommend a database or a different way as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: just by way of information: IDA disassembler has "FLIRT signature" files that it uses to try to determine this kind of information, and it is moderately successful.  so, since it has been programmed before, yes, it is possible.  i'm sure it's a massive effort to do this though, and you would need to either generate your own or use someone else's signatures.  also, it's not a 100% success rate, *especially for optimized files*.  if the file has been optimized it's almost impossible (even by hand using a nice tool like IDA) to figure out exactly which functions are what from the libraries.

Comment: for debug builds, it might be more feasible.  but i would say if a tool that has been around as long as IDA has still can't do it, you are going to have a long road ahead of you if you try to roll your own solution here, and it's likely to still be quite imperfect and not come even close to 100% on highly-optimized files. link to ida if you want to check it out: http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/ (i am not sure how much functionality the demo version has but it should at least give you an idea, i think, of what i am describing.)

Comment: @shelleybutterfly actually, my purpose of this question is to ask how IDA achieves this....

Comment: ahh :) ok, well, let's put it this way then: since you're not expecting 100% accuracy, and you are familiar with IDA, will you work with me to narrow down the problem space a little on your  requirements are for an acceptable answer? **starting points:** is the time frame the two remaining days on the bounty? is a concept allowing for something like FLIRT signatures good enough? does it need to handle optimized files? deal with obfuscated executables? only win PEs? do you need any working test outputs? if so, can we choose an .exe ahead of time to test on, perhaps one we build ourselves? :D

Comment: Yes, about 2 days left. FLIRT is good, but I am not sure where I can _enough_. It needs to handle optimized / obfuscated files, but as an answer here, it is not required to be. PE is enough for now. Test outputs are fine, of course. You can just build as simple as a .exe print out some lines after <cmath> abs/sqrt/pow or <algorithm> sort etc. Nice comments.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly, and if you put your effort as answer, you have a high chance to win the bounty. ^-^

Comment: :) well, unfortunately the timing just isn't working out on the bounty; i was hoping to be able to tackle it but after it took me [mumble] hours just to go through the spec and winnt.h and with various other obligations tonight and tomorrow, it is highly impossible that i will get anywhere on this before next week. ;) but, it is interesting and i am still willing to try to help find at least a start of a solution for you middle to late next week once i get a little time; wish i had noticed your question a few days earlier. :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is assuming you want to analyze a standard Windows executable that is dynamically linked against other import libraries (.lib and assoicated .dll files that are not statically linked), and if this is the case, you want to interperet the PE (Portable Executable) file structure.

Here's a [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx) to get you started, with sample code on dumping the PE header.

You will want to focus on the Import table (.idata section) for external library calls, and the Export table (.edata section) for calls defined inside the executable and marked as exportable (usually this only exists in .dll files).

For static libraries, their format is called COFF, and there is the [DUMPBIN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) utility that ships with Visual Studio that you can use to quickly peer into your lib files and even dump the disassembly of the code if you wanted.

> The DUMPBIN utility, which is provided with the 32-bit version of
>   Microsoft Visual C++, combines the abilities of the LINK, LIB, and
>   EXEHDR utilities. The combination of these tools features the ability
>   to provide information about the format and symbols provided in
>   executable, library, and DLL files.

For information on the structure of COFF files, see this [article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/hood0498.aspx).

Figuring out if a function call is from a lib or not would be tricky, but from what I remember, most static lib calls in code are actually thunk calls (simple jmp calls to the actual object code copied in from the lib) and are small in size (usually around 5 bytes), while "user defined" ones are not thunks, and are bp-based framed calls.

Comment: My question is: how to distinguish them? You criterion does not seem to be clear.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for?  In the first part of my answer, if you are using an import library dynamically linked, your "library functions" will all appear in the Import table of the PE file.

Comment: How to distinguish static linked functions with user self-written function?

Answer (score 1):

When your programm is linked, static functions and user-define functions are 
include file by file.

So if you dump the header of a PE file, and look at the symbols 
table (using objdump -x if you run with mingw32, or anything else)
you will see the name of a file and then all functions import from this one, 
after an other file name and its functions...
Or if you have debug information, may be this can be easier.

So after you link functions with a file you can sort the functions by analysing their file name. Looking for extention (.c / .lib / .a) or check in a list of file you have somwhere.
Be carefull to eliminate crt0 files...

However this is kind a tricky solution and I'm not sure this'll work for every program.

Comment: What you said is dynamic link.

Comment: No, for dynamic link you just have to read a flag and you will not have the code for the function. Here you have a function and its code is on the .text section. So no difference with user-define code. But you can read from which source file it's coming from...

Comment: So I have to maintain a database of "source"?

Comment: Enjoy your new privileges. However, please answer my question in the last comment if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty ;). Yeah you have to maintain a database of source. In fact when you create a static library it's just an archive of object file (.o / .obj). Their files are included with the one of your program when you link to the library. So the unique difference between linked functions and user-define functions will be the file they come from.